# Multi variable clustering cartographical data

Tags: clustering, multiple-comparisons, hierarchical-clustering, model-based-clustering

Firstly , my knowledge in statistics is very limited , so excuse me if I'm ask a none well placed question.

I have a country  ,( example : USA ) , and i have 3 set of data 
1) position (lat , lng ) of every food storage (S) .
2) every storage have a variable C with , the C is the capacity .
3) a group of position (lat , lng) to specifing boards of every state

I need to cluster this data based on distance , capacity , and the border of any cluster need to be as similar to state boards

Ex : we need to create 3 k
The output will be : 33% of the capacities of all storages house in the first cluster , the second 33% , etc ... But that not mean the cluster will take 33% of the map , because that will gives an inequality between clusters .
Note , the border alignment for states is used to to the same effect of a map matching .

What clustering algorithm i need to use ?
And any idea of how i can create a visual image for this clustering ? 
Thanks

Comment: Question is unclear, try to explain better. You need to create 3 k... what? What are the 33 %?

Comment: @user2974951 , yes , 3 k , k is number of cluster 
3 k means 3 clusters , ( but its can be 4 , 10 , 1000 , ) it's just an example 
and about the 33% ,  if we have a 100% and 3 cluster , every cluster will have 33% ( is just an example again ) , if we have 4 cluster , every cluster will take 25% ...

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796682/group-n-points-in-k-clusters-of-equal-size, if this is what you need.